# How to get only Years and days between two dates except months

Tags: javascript, .net, outsystems

I have an expiry date. I just want to calculate the years and days between the expiry date and current date.
I don't need months. example my expiry date is 15/05/2027 means I need the result of 4 years 32 days

```
"Years "+ (Trunc(DiffDays(CurrDate(),Expirydate)/365))+ "Days "+ If((Day(CurrDate())-Day(Expirydate))>0,(Day(CurrDate())-Day(Expirydate)),(Day(Expirydate))-(Day(CurrDate())))
```

this code works only for the same month. If I choose a month ahead then shows zero days.

Comment: Are you sure you want 32 as days result? The days between 15th May and 14th March sum up to 61. I would humbly assume that this is the days-amount you wanted to calc.

Comment: You could do it with division trough 365, but that wouldn't take lead years into considerations. It's probably doable to do it with standard Outsystems functions but because of difficulties with date comparison in the form of Leap years, time zones, length of months, etc I would recommend writing an extension in c# implementing a library or code sample which already proved itself to be reliable date comparison tool.

Comment: Perhaps you can make use of the [date-time-utils](https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-documentation/9759/date-time-utils)  forge component which already implemented a `Year_DateDiff` action or perhaps some other component.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible for you to use a 3rd party lib such as [day.js](https://day.js.org/) I would recommend using it.

Then you could handle your case as follows:

```
const expiryDate = dayjs('05/15/2027')
const yearsTilExp = expiryDate.diff(Date(), 'year')
const nowInExpYear = dayjs().add(expiryDate.diff(Date(), 'year'), 'year')
const daysTilExp = expiryDate.diff(nowInExpYear, 'day')
```

Answer (score -1):

Please post your entire code in here.
But are you looking for something like this?

Updated my code to your question. Pure Js and simple.

```
const startDate = new Date('2022-01-01');
const endDate = new Date('2023-01-02');

const differenceMs = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();

const oneYearMs = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
const years = Math.floor(differenceMs / oneYearMs);
const days = Math.floor((differenceMs % oneYearMs) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

console.log(`Year(s): ${years} and ${days} day(s)`);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this functions

helper fns

```
// seconds in days
const secondsToDays = s =>  s / 86400000

// check leap year
function isLeapYear(year) {
  return (year & 3) == 0 && ((year % 25) != 0 || (year & 15) == 0)
}
```

calc days in all years from today to your date

```
const calcDays = d => {
  // get years to check leap year
  const y1 = new Date(d).getFullYear()
  const y2 = new Date().getFullYear()
  let daysInYears = 0
  let yDiff = y1 - y2

  if (isLeapYear(y1)) {
    // if is leap year and date is less then 29 of Februaby
    const d1 = new Date(new Date(d).getTime()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    const d2 = new Date(new Date(y2, 1, 29).getTime()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
    if (d1 < d2) {
      daysInYears += 365
      if (yDiff) yDiff--
    }
  } else {
    daysInYears += 365
  }
  // calc all days
  for (let x = 1; x < yDiff; x++ ) {
    let i1 = new Date(y2 + x, 2, 0).getDate()
    if (i1 == 29) {
      daysInYears += 366
    } else {
      daysInYears += 365
    }
  }
  
  yDiff = y1 - y2
  // return middle point of days in all years
  return daysInYears / yDiff
}
```

and for the end use all fns to cacludate difference between today and expired days

```
const calcYearDaysDiff = d => {
  const d1 = new Date(new Date(d).getTime()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  const d2 = new Date(new Date().getTime()).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  
  let t = d1 - d2
  let s = secondsToDays(t)
  let days = calcDays(d)
  let y = s / days
  return 'Years:' + Math.floor(y) +'. Days:' + Math.floor(s % days)
}

calcYearDaysDiff('2027-05-15')
```

Result is: 'Years:4. Days:61'
is so clear. without any libraries. only pure js

We get difference in milliseconds for today and for you date
Then calculate all days in years between two dates

and get the years and days between the expiry date and current date